# installing dll which exist in target directory to install directory using cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have a target in CMake which is a shared library (.dll) and it depends on some other dlls which is added to system using find_packages.

the came is used mainly in Windows with VS (1029)

other dlls are copied to target directory (for example release or debug) during a build on VC.

Now I want to add an install target.

I have this code:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/win-Install)

install(TARGETS myDLL RUNTIME DESTINATION bin CONFIGURATIONS Release)
```

This copy my dll to install directory but not the dependent libraries.

How can make sure that the install also copies all dependent libraries to install directory?

I tried to use a `FILE(GLOB_RECURSE All_DLLS  "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY }/*.dll")`
but it did not work.

How can make sure that install copies all dependent libraries (*.dlls) to install directory?

Apparently,

```
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE All_DLLS  "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY }/*.dll")
```

is run during cmake execution, but I need a command that works and detect *.dlls in build directory when install target in VS is runs.

Comment: "*I tried to use a `FILE(GLOB_RECURSE All_DLLS  "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY }/*.dll")` but it did not work.*"... why not? How did it not work? Were the DLLs not present in that directory yet?

Comment: @squareskittles The line that you mentioned is run during cmake call. At this time the build directories are not created and so there is no file there. I think I should find a solution as part of install command which would run inside VS and copies all *.dll as at that time the output directory (such as build/release) is created and all dll files are copied into it.

Comment: Did you check the [INSTALL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#files) function ? (especially the Install directories part). Does something like that `install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY} DESTINATION mydest FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.dll")` work for you ?

Comment: @mans Thanks for the clarification. You could also use `install(FILES ...` and list the DLL files explicitly that need to be installed. Remember, you can also use generator expressions (such as `<TARGET_FILE_DIR:SomeTarget>`) to get the directory containing the DLLs.